# Solaris 11 zones, networking and blocked ports

Tags: networking, firewall, solaris-zones

Our Solaris admin quit.  We are building a new system.  I have been tasked to help.

I have a Solaris box with a global zone and 15 non-global zones.
Some NGZs can ssh to other NGZ.  Many cannot ssh at all.  I can zlogin from GZ to all NGZ.

Here is how I have tried to troubleshoot:

`1) copy a master hosts file to all zones
2) ssh -vvv somehost* (for problem zones this hangs at " debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0  debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22."
3) telnet somehost 22  (for problem zones this never connects)`

One last caveat:  I was told there was a firewall NGZ built in the original design that was never implemented, but no way to prove it.

How can I track down the source blocking these ports

Comment: I think you may want this article: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19044-01/sol.containers/817-1592/z.admin.ov-9/index.html

Specifically the "Shared-IP Network Interfaces" section.

Answer (score 1):

On the global zone, can you display the output of `zoneadm list -iv`?

Also, for you're problem zone, from the global as root, have you tried:  `zlogin -C <zone_name>` to get to the zone's console?  Perhaps it was never fully setup and will prompt you to do some configuration.  If that's not it, at least you'll have a way to get into the zone to verify it's state (ie: `svcs -xv`; and looking at /var/adm/messages).